# Can't add tag to service definition in compiler pass

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony

I have bundle in my symfony project and I want to change `doctrine.orm.listeners.resolve_target_entity` service in this bundle. I make it in compiler pass

symfony/symfony                      v3.2.3
doctrine/common                      v2.7.2
doctrine/dbal                        v2.5.12
doctrine/orm                         v2.5.6
doctrine/doctrine-bundle             1.6.7

```
namespace XXX\MyBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\PassConfig;
use XXX\MyBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler\PreparePass;

class XXXMyBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        parent::build($container);
        $container->addCompilerPass(new PreparePass());
    }
}
```

---

```
namespace XXX\MyBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CompilerPassInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;

class PreparePass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $definition = $container->findDefinition('doctrine.orm.listeners.resolve_target_entity');

        $definition->addMethodCall('addResolveTargetEntity', array(
            'class1', 'class2', array(),
        ));

        $definition->addTag('doctrine.event_subscriber', array());
    }
}
```

Method call is added, tag is added, `./bin/console debug:container` shows that everything is ok. But by fact service is not added to doctrine subscribers, there is no code for it in container dump in `getDoctrine_Dbal_DefaultConnectionService` function.

If I register my bundle before DoctrineBundle it works, if after it doesn't work :) I couldn't find where `doctrine.event_subscriber` tag is processed.

Is it possible to make it to work regardless of bundles registration order? And where `doctrine.event_subscriber` tag is processed?

Any help, thanks

Comment: Which version of Symfony and Doctrine do you use ?

Comment: Please also share with us code where you register your compiler pass.

Comment: I've updated my question

Comment: What do you think adding a tag to the listeners service is going to do?  Normally you just define your subscribers and tag them.  I don't see the point in fooling around with the doctrine services themselves.  The event_subscriber tag will be processed in the DoctrineBundle.  Might also look at priorities: http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-2-compiler-passes-improvements

Comment: @Cerad I don't want to change doctrine config. Setting priority has helped me. Thanks!